# How to change all external links with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I want to replace all my external links using Javascript..
I just want to add "http://example.com/go=" before every external links...
How will I do that?
Please help..

Comment: What have you tried so far and do you mean all links in anchor tags?

Comment: Do you mean replace all anchor tags links in a page? And what do you mean by external, are there internal links you do not want to replace?

Comment: yes.. all external links in anchor tags.. I don't want to change any internal links..

Comment: So select all the links,  loop over, check domain, if not current, replace. `javascript stackoverflow get all external links` search probably will give tons of dupes.

Comment: I am not expert on that.. Can you please give me that code?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `document.links` `HTMLCollection` and set `.href` property to the required string if the current `.href` does not include `document.domain`

```
Array.from(document.links)
.forEach(link => 
  link.href = new RegExp(document.domain).test(link.href)
              ? link.href : "http://example.com/go=")
```

Comment: But this will also replace internal links.

Comment: @NewToJS "adding the old link to the end of `http://example.com/go=`"? Not sure what you mean?

Comment: May be it will be better to use `link.href.startsWith(document.origin)`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Yes, there are number of ways to implement the test, depending of what current `.href` string is. Though the `.href`,  would not start with "example.com", but rather the protocol, yes?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet should work. It iterates over all `<a>` elements and checks if the `href` contains the current domain (I test it using an RegExp, but there's also solutions thinkable as well). If not, the prefix is added.

```js
const originReg = new RegExp(location.hostname, 'i');

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  if (originReg.test(a.href)) return /* internal link */;
  
  a.href = `http://example.com/go?url=${encodeURI(a.href)}`;
});
```

```html
<a href="/bar">Bar</a>
<a href="baz">Baz</a>
<a href="http://example.com/foo">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((anchor) => {

  // make sure we return the relative path, not the absolute
  // getAttribute(), not .href
  const href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
  const str = 'http://example.com/go=';

  // if the link is an external link, update
  // the href attribute
  /:\/\//.test(href) && anchor.setAttribute('href', str + href);
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln2L3bf7/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will only target external links.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((anchor) => {

  // make sure we return the relative path, not the absolute
  const target = anchor.getAttribute('target');

   If ( target === '_blank' ){
        const href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
        const str = 'http://example.com/go=';

       anchor.setAttribute('href', str + href);
  }
});
```

// most of this was an edit to @Andy code. I did not want to make major changes to what was there.