# Edit external links with javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's my current code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((anchor) => {
        const href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
        /:\/\//.test(href) && anchor.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/go=' + href);
        console.log(anchor.getAttribute('href'));
    });
}
```

The code is supposed to add `http://example.com/go=` before all external links.

If I link to an external page, it is adding it correctly.  However, it's also adding it to internal pages depending on how I link to them.  If I link to them like `<a href="/testing">` it doesn't added it (which is correct.

But if I link to my website like `<a href="http://website.com/testing">` then it's assuming that's an external URL since I included the domain and adding the string before it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change all external links with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268205/how-to-change-all-external-links-with-javascript)

Comment: Code on that page doesn't work, which is why it's been re-posted here.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show how you implemented the code from the proposed duplicate and how it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the regular expression you use to test with one that also checks that the `href` domain does not bein with `website.com`: change

```
/:\/\//
```

to

```
/:\/\/(?!website\.com)/
```

You also might consider using an `if` statement instead of `&&`, to make the code more readable (leave the tricky-looking `&&`-as-`if` to the minifiers):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((anchor) => {
  const href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
  if (/:\/\/(?!website\.com)/.test(href)) {
    anchor.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/go=' + href);
  }
  console.log(anchor.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

Also note that `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an array, and only *newer* browsers support `NodeList.prototype.forEach` - Chrome users on Vista and older systems will run into errors, for example, so if you want to support them, make sure to include a polyfill, if you aren't already.

If you have to, you can dynamically create the regular expression from the current domain by checking `window.location.hostname`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((anchor) => {
  const { hostname } = window.location;
  const escapedHostname = hostname.replace(/\./g, '\\.');
  const pattern = new RegExp(`://(?!${escapedHostname})`);
  const href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
  if (pattern.test(href)) {
    anchor.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/go=' + href);
  }
  console.log(anchor.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the current domain without having to hard code it into the code?  The code will be distributed across multiple domains, with new ones added daily :/